# right derivative vs a right limit of the derivative times smallness factor

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

In the question

[Question on one-sided derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629388/question-on-one-sided-derivatives),

it is shown that if $f$ is differentiable on 
$]x_0,x_0+\delta[$ for some $\delta>0$, such that
$\;\lim_{x\rightarrow {x_{0}}^{+}}f^{\prime}(x)\;$ exists, then 
$$f^{\prime}_{+}(x_{0})=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_0)}{\epsilon}$$
exists, but the converse is not true.

Question:
Suppose $f$ is differentiable on 
$]x_0,x_0+\delta[$ for some $\delta>0$.
Can $f^{\prime}_{+}(x_{0})$ exist but the limit
$\;\lim_{x\rightarrow {x_{0}}^{+}}(x-x_{0})f^{\prime}(x)\;$ does not exist ?

In other words, does the existence of 
$f^{\prime}_{+}(x_{0})$ imply the existence of the limit $\;\lim_{x\rightarrow {x_{0}}^{+}}(x-x_{0})f^{\prime}(x)\;$ ?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. Let me correct the question.

Comment: Yes. This is a counterexample. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: $x_0=0$, $f(0)=0$, and
$$f(x)=x^2\sin(x^{-3})$$
for $x\ne0$.